# Matrix initialization not working with higher values

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

I have to initialize a matrix which has to be later passed to a Cuda kernel. But I get a segmentation fault when I initialize the matrix. The code is as follows -

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    size_t m = 512;
    size_t k = 32; 
    size_t n = 32;
    
    float* a = (float*) malloc(m * k * sizeof(float));
    
    if(a == nullptr){
        std::cout<<"Nullptr returned, Check Memory Hardware"<<std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
    
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    
        for(size_t j=0; j<k; j++){
            std::cout<<j<<"  ";
            a[i*m + j] = 1.0f;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl<<"=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- ||||| =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code only works when `m < 100`;

For `m < 100`, It throws a segmentation fault at `i = 97`.

I was able to use matrices of side 2^12 with the exact same code.

My system configuration - RAM 16GB 2667 MT/s, i7 9750h and RTX 2070.

Comment: What a reason of using malloc in C++?

Comment: `i*m + j` is a wrong way to compute a linear index.

Comment: `RAM 16GB` -- That memory does you no good if your application is 32-bit, just saying.  A 64-bit app can utilize that memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[i*m + j] = 1.0f;
```

This math is wrong. Using the terminology of `i` representing the row and `j` representing the column, there are `k` values per row, therefore this should be:

```
a[i*k + j] = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Oh god Yes, thanks a lot for pointing it out. I've had some hardware trouble recently and freaked out. Sorry for it though